# Accessing AWS SDK for .NET inside a MVC 5 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to access my S3 Bucket in a MVC .NET Web Application. Therefore I use the AWS SDK for .NET. I'am doing this with the following call:

```
var request = new ListObjectsRequest
{
     BucketName = bucketName,
     MaxKeys = maxEntries,
     Delimiter = delimiter,
     Prefix = prefix
};

var response = _amazonS3Client.ListObjects(request);
```

When I run this code in a Console Application it is working fine. When I try to implement the same to a MCV .NET Application, I run into this error:

**"A WebException with status ConnectFailure was thrown."**

```
>    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.WebExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext
> executionContext, WebException exception)    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext
> executionContext, Exception exception)    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext
> executionContext, Exception exception)    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.<InvokeAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    bei
> Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    bei
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    bei
> ContiTeves.AWS.S3.S3GetClient.<ListFoldersAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
> --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    bei
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> bei
> MyMvcWebTest.Controllers.AwsController.<GetFoldersFromBucket>d__1.MoveNext()
> in
> \MyMvcWebTest\sources\MyMvcWebTest\Controllers\AwsController.cs:Zeile
> 43.
```

It seems that some how its not possible to access AWS out of my Web Application. For sure I need to configure something in the Web.config or do I need to change a configuration in my IIS (express).

Does anyone has a solution for this Problem? Thank you!

Comment: What is the full text of exception, and the stack trace, and are there nested exceptions?

Comment: I added some more details